# How to create a form that updates multiple field for multiple user simultaneously in Django?

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite, django-forms

I want to create a form that able to take multiple respond and update the database for multiple instances.

Here is my case:
I have 2 models, Members and Cash

```
class Members(models.Model):
    nim = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    position = models.CharField(
        max_length=30,
        choices=POSITION_OPTION,
    )
    year = models.IntegerField()
    program = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    potrait = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='NO PHOTO')

class Cash(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(Members, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    jan = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    feb = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    mar = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    apr = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    may = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    jun = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    jul = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    aug = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    sep = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

The logic behind this model is, each Member has their record of Cash. So my end goal is to sum the number of True in each Member and determine how much cash they have deposited to
the organization.

Back to the topic, I want to create a form page that is formed like tables,

---

| NIM | January | February | So on... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 010456 | [ ] (checkbox) | [ ] (checkbox) | So on... |
| ----------- | --------------------------- | --------------------------- | ------------------ |
| 010457 | [ ] (checkbox) | [ ] (checkbox) | So on... |

```
                             <button>UPDATE RECORD</button>
```

But I'm stuck at figuring out how to connect this multiple form to multiple user at once.

The alternative way I can achieve my end goal is to create separate form page for each user, but that'll kill the purpose of creating this form, which is to simplify Cash system in my organization.

That's all, any feedback is appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest using `Formsets`, namely the `modelformset_factory` method. Here I have created a CashFormSet for the Cash model. The `form` template displays all entries. You mark the ones you need and click the `update` button.

After checking for the 'POST' method and validation, the data is saved. Data aggregation occurs and nim, count are displayed in the `base1` template.

Doc: [Formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/forms/formsets/)

Doc: [modelformset_factory](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/forms/models/#django.forms.models.modelformset_factory)

views.py

```
from django.forms import modelformset_factory
from django.db.models import Count, Q

CashFormSet = modelformset_factory(Cash, fields='__all__', extra=0)

def form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CashFormSet(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            memcash = (Members.objects.annotate
                (
                cnt=Count('cash', filter=Q(cash__jan=True)) +
                    Count('cash', filter=Q(cash__feb=True)) +
                    Count('cash', filter=Q(cash__mar=True)) +
                    Count('cash', filter=Q(cash__apr=True)) +
                    Count('cash', filter=Q(cash__may=True)) +
                    Count('cash', filter=Q(cash__jun=True)) +
                    Count('cash', filter=Q(cash__jul=True)) +
                    Count('cash', filter=Q(cash__aug=True)) +
                    Count('cash', filter=Q(cash__sep=True))
            ))

            return render(request, 'base1.html', {'memcash': memcash})
    else:
        form = CashFormSet()

    return render(request, 'form.html', {'form': form})
```

form.html

```
<form method='post' action=''>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.management_form }}
    {% for field in form %}

    <p>{{ field }}</p>

    {% endfor %}

    <button type='submit'>update</button>
</form>
```

base1.html

```
{% for field in memcash %}

<p>{{ 'nim' }} : {{ field.nim }} {{ 'count' }} : {{ field.cnt }}</p>

{% endfor %}
```